# Every time my three-year-old bashes the keyboard randomly my hot corners stop working. What key combo is she pressing?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, children

Whenever I make the mistake and leave my MBP unattended and unlocked for more than a minute, my three-year-old rushes in and starts randomly mashing keys on the keyboard, pretending to type.  Every time, without fail, afterward, things seem OK but the hot corners no longer work and the Dock (which I normally have set to auto-hide) will not rise up from the bottom of the screen when hovering there; I must click the mouse at the bottom of the screen, where the Dock is hiding, in order to make it rise.  Merely hovering, like usual, does not make the Dock rise.

What key combination is she pressing to trigger this behavior?  And how can I turn it off without having to completely restart the computer?

Comment: set up lock screen to prevent future attacks.

Comment: Just make sure the screen saver is entertaining enough

Comment: Solution: set up a video camera next time and analyze the footage :D

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you please clarify what do you mean by `I must click in order to make it rise.` in the end of first paragraph?

Comment: @NimeshNeema I have edited that sentence to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: @Sean Thanks, that serves the purpose. Can you verify if you need to click or just hovering the cursor all the way to the edge does the job?

Comment: @NimeshNeema I need to click at the very bottom of the screen to get the Dock to rise.  Hovering there, even if it's at the very bottom, does not make the Dock rise when this problem occurs.  I have edited my post again to try and clarify that .

Comment: Lets be clear here, there is no controlling the 3 Yr old. Set up your screen to lock after time set or to lock  placing the cursor in a corner.

Comment: Author says "more than a minute". Sounds like you'd need a 30 second lock timeout for that to work, which would be very annoying.

Comment: Get her her own machine...

Answer (score 1):

You can search through the keyboard shortcuts with System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts.

For me, "Turn Dock Hiding On/Off" is <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> D

I don't see a keyboard shortcut for enabling/disabling Hot Corners (in High Sierra), though maybe your list is different?